# How to refer to variable in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, loops, cluster-computing

I have a `test` folder containing two files: `test.txt` and `test2.txt`. I want to copy these files from `test` to the `test2` directory using a for loop and bsub. Here is the script I wrote, which is called `looptest.sh`.

```
looptest.sh
#!/bin/bash
cp ~/test/$F ~/test2
```

This is the for loop I typed in the command line:

```
for F in 'ls -l' ; do
bsub -n 2 -q short looptest.sh "$F" ;
done
```

I run the command from the `test` folder, but it's not working, and I think it has to do with the way I refer to `"F"`. Any thoughts?

Comment: Don't use `ls` to select files.

Comment: Your `$F` in looptest.sh should be `"$1"`, since presumably you need to refer to the first argument of that script.

Comment: Always double quote referred variables: `"$1"` in looptest.sh, etc.

Comment: [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net) points at `'ls -l'` and says "[This is a literal string](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2041). To run as a command, use $(..) instead of '..' ."

Comment: Use `find(1)` to select your files and to also then run a script on them: see the `-exec` option of `find(1)`.

Comment: I need to confess that I did not know `bsub`.

Comment: If you just want to loop over files in the current directory, `for F in *; do` is fine (except it'd be better to use a lower- or mixed-case variable name instead of `F`). BTW, I recommend [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) for pointing out common scripting mistakes. Also, put `set -x` before script sections that aren't working right, and bash will print the commands (or their equivalents) as it executes them.